# CPU, Memory > 50% with no traffic

Tags: nginx, centos, php

I've a 1 GB 1 CPU droplet on Digital Ocean.

OS: CentOS 7

PHP: PHP 7.2.2, PHP-FPM

Web Server: Nginx

DB: Mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB

---

With hardly any traffic (<20 visitors per day), many times DO's monitoring agent reports CPU>50% and RAM>50% at random times of the day.

What is the best approach to identify what & where the problem may be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system doesn't have a problem. The operating system uses whatever RAM it needs, including caching of files, maintenance, maybe some batch processes.

If you run out of RAM or CPU then you have either a busy system that needs more resource, or a problem. Until that happens don't worry about it.

Comment: And then "problem" may be "crappy programming", which is not a serverfault but a stackoverflow problem.

Comment: I've Wordpress running (latest version) with a few popular plugins. So this possibility can be safely is eliminated.